# split(" +") and split(" ") are different

Tags: java, split, whitespace

I want to erase the vacuum in the String.

```
String input = "java example.java       aaa     bbb";
String[] temp = input.trim().split(" ");
```

that result is

> java 
> example.java
> aaa
> bbb

but i want result that

> java
> example.java
> aaa
> bbb

so, i use the split(" +"). The result is right.
but i don't understand, how doing the split(" +").

Comment: The argument is a regular expression. See the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class for regular expression constructs. The `+` means "one or more of the previous expression, e.g. one or more spaces in your case.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. your comment is basic solution.

Answer (score 5):

[split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) takes a regex as it's argument. "+" in regex means "one or more of the previous element". So splitting on " +" will split on "one or more spaces".

Answer (score 3):

- In first case it's a normal string split.
- Where as in second case, you took help of  [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

From docs of split() method

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

A simple space don't have any expression where as `+` have.

`string.split(" +")` to set the split delimiter to `one or more of the previous element`, in your case be any number of white space characters (" ").

Answer (score 1):

Best way to provide the regex for whitespace is using `\\s+`. Which is one or more space.

```
String input = "java example.java       aaa     bbb";
String[] temp = input.trim().split("\\s+");
```

> If you are expecting only single space then use `\\s` for single white space.
>
> For more than one white space always use `\\s+`, that is what happening in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to String.split() is a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or regular expression. Passing " " means it will match on *exactly one* space, passing " +" means it will match on *one or more* spaces.

There's a good tutorial on regexs here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

"+" in regex means one or more from previous , so " +" means one or more spaces.
Refer [regex syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

And the argument in split method is regex <strike>not string as most believe</strike>. Refer [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The argument is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for the text between items that gets thrown away.

With `" "`, the string is cut up as `"java", " ", "example.java", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "aaa", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "", " ", "bbb"`, and then the `" "` are thrown away, leaving `"java", "example.java", "", "", "", "", "", "", "aaa", "", "", "", "", "bbb"`. Where there are many spaces in a row, each space matches the `" "` pattern separately, and there is an empty string `""` in between each pair of spaces.

With `" +"`, it means that any group of one or more spaces is a single match. So the string is cut up as `"java", " ", "example.java", "       ", "aaa", "     ", "bbb"`, and the space groups are thrown away, leaving `"java", "example.java", "aaa", "bbb"`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `string.split("\\s+")`, `\\s` is any `white-space` character (space, tab, enter...)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between .split(" ") and .split(+) is:

The regex `" ":`

- Match the space character literally.

The regex `(" +")`:

- Match a single whitespacecharacter (tab, line feed, carriage return,
  vertical tab, form feed) between one and unlimmited times. (greedy)

Short:

> " "   splits the array at one single space character.
>
> /\s/ splits the array at every kind of whitespace character
>
> '+'      Matches between one and unlimitted times